# How to append data in list() without assigning it in a variable in python Interpreter

Tags: python, python-3.x, interpreter

How to Append Data in list() without assign variable in Python Interpreter?
I am trying to in this code

list([1, 2]).append(3)

Output is : None

and I get output Like this
[1, 2, 3]

Comment: Try `[1,2] + [3]`?

Comment: or use extend()

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can just type [1, 2, 3] or [1, 2] + [3]